# ¿Cómo hacer un gráfico de velas junto con líneas de tendencia pero considerando un eje y con valores de cambio porcentual usando MatPlotLib y Python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, gráficas, visualización-de-datos, ciencia-de-datos

Cuando estaba tratando de comparar 3 activos financieros basados exclusivamente en su serie de precios, me di cuenta de que para hacerlo, todas esas series de precios tenían que convertirse en series de cambio porcentual de precios, de modo que uno pudiera ver correctamente cuál de ellos estaba teniendo un mejor desempeño durante un período de tiempo.

Más tarde, configuré un gráfico personalizado en **TradingView** que me permitió visualizar exactamente lo que quería hacer por mi parte, aquí:

[image: Salida deseada]

Este gráfico personalizado básicamente muestra:

- La serie de cambio de precio de 3 activos financieros, estas series de cambio de precio se calculan de la siguiente manera: `(Precio de cierre - Primer precio de apertura)/(Primer precio de apertura)`. (*Tenga en cuenta también que estas series se actualizan automáticamente en función de los datos que se están considerando en esa plataforma, por lo que si acerca o aleja el gráfico principal, la serie de cambio de precio también cambiará).*
- El gráfico de velas de uno de los activos, en este caso es **BNBUSDT**, ya que mi interés es encontrar un patrón de velas en ese activo.
- El período de tiempo en el que se registraron estos datos, cuya fecha de inicio fue `"14 de septiembre de 2022 01:00:00 UTC"` y la fecha de finalización fue `"14 de septiembre de 2022 23:00:00 UTC"`, además cada vela representa 1 hora de datos y toda esta información se solicitó a Binance Exchange.

Entonces, puse mi cerebro a trabajar y logré obtener este resultado:

[image: Salida actual]

Usando esta info:

- `df_chg_btc`

|  | Start Date | % Chg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2410 | 2022-09-14 01:00:00 | 0.51 |
| 2411 | 2022-09-14 02:00:00 | 1.22 |
| 2412 | 2022-09-14 03:00:00 | 0.62 |
| 2413 | 2022-09-14 04:00:00 | 0.95 |
| 2414 | 2022-09-14 05:00:00 | 0.58 |
| 2415 | 2022-09-14 06:00:00 | 0.2 |
| 2416 | 2022-09-14 07:00:00 | 0.22 |
| 2417 | 2022-09-14 08:00:00 | 0.92 |
| 2418 | 2022-09-14 09:00:00 | 0.74 |
| 2419 | 2022-09-14 10:00:00 | 0.7 |
| 2420 | 2022-09-14 11:00:00 | 0.13 |
| 2421 | 2022-09-14 12:00:00 | 0.55 |
| 2422 | 2022-09-14 13:00:00 | 0.56 |
| 2423 | 2022-09-14 14:00:00 | 0.47 |
| 2424 | 2022-09-14 15:00:00 | -0.1 |
| 2425 | 2022-09-14 16:00:00 | -0.28 |
| 2426 | 2022-09-14 17:00:00 | -0.46 |
| 2427 | 2022-09-14 18:00:00 | -2.08 |
| 2428 | 2022-09-14 19:00:00 | -1.22 |
| 2429 | 2022-09-14 20:00:00 | -1.25 |
| 2430 | 2022-09-14 21:00:00 | 0.02 |
| 2431 | 2022-09-14 22:00:00 | 0.48 |
| 2432 | 2022-09-14 23:00:00 | 0.14 |

- `df_chg_eth`

|  | Start Date | % Chg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2410 | 2022-09-14 01:00:00 | 0.59 |
| 2411 | 2022-09-14 02:00:00 | 1.75 |
| 2412 | 2022-09-14 03:00:00 | 1.87 |
| 2413 | 2022-09-14 04:00:00 | 3.04 |
| 2414 | 2022-09-14 05:00:00 | 2.53 |
| 2415 | 2022-09-14 06:00:00 | 2.18 |
| 2416 | 2022-09-14 07:00:00 | 2.45 |
| 2417 | 2022-09-14 08:00:00 | 1.88 |
| 2418 | 2022-09-14 09:00:00 | 2.0 |
| 2419 | 2022-09-14 10:00:00 | 1.79 |
| 2420 | 2022-09-14 11:00:00 | 1.38 |
| 2421 | 2022-09-14 12:00:00 | 2.02 |
| 2422 | 2022-09-14 13:00:00 | 2.01 |
| 2423 | 2022-09-14 14:00:00 | 1.82 |
| 2424 | 2022-09-14 15:00:00 | 1.36 |
| 2425 | 2022-09-14 16:00:00 | 0.75 |
| 2426 | 2022-09-14 17:00:00 | 1.0 |
| 2427 | 2022-09-14 18:00:00 | 0.35 |
| 2428 | 2022-09-14 19:00:00 | 1.67 |
| 2429 | 2022-09-14 20:00:00 | 1.84 |
| 2430 | 2022-09-14 21:00:00 | 2.98 |
| 2431 | 2022-09-14 22:00:00 | 4.15 |
| 2432 | 2022-09-14 23:00:00 | 4.12 |

- `df_chg`

|  | Start Date | % Chg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2410 | 2022-09-14 01:00:00 | -0.14 |
| 2411 | 2022-09-14 02:00:00 | 0.54 |
| 2412 | 2022-09-14 03:00:00 | 0.72 |
| 2413 | 2022-09-14 04:00:00 | 1.26 |
| 2414 | 2022-09-14 05:00:00 | 0.83 |
| 2415 | 2022-09-14 06:00:00 | 0.22 |
| 2416 | 2022-09-14 07:00:00 | 0.4 |
| 2417 | 2022-09-14 08:00:00 | 0.76 |
| 2418 | 2022-09-14 09:00:00 | 0.68 |
| 2419 | 2022-09-14 10:00:00 | 0.58 |
| 2420 | 2022-09-14 11:00:00 | 0.58 |
| 2421 | 2022-09-14 12:00:00 | 0.5 |
| 2422 | 2022-09-14 13:00:00 | 1.22 |
| 2423 | 2022-09-14 14:00:00 | 0.79 |
| 2424 | 2022-09-14 15:00:00 | 0.54 |
| 2425 | 2022-09-14 16:00:00 | 0.07 |
| 2426 | 2022-09-14 17:00:00 | -0.07 |
| 2427 | 2022-09-14 18:00:00 | -0.83 |
| 2428 | 2022-09-14 19:00:00 | -0.18 |
| 2429 | 2022-09-14 20:00:00 | -0.04 |
| 2430 | 2022-09-14 21:00:00 | 0.5 |
| 2431 | 2022-09-14 22:00:00 | 0.61 |
| 2432 | 2022-09-14 23:00:00 | 0.47 |

- `df_ohlc`

|  | Start Date | Open Price | High Price | Low Price | Close Price | Volume | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2410 | 2022-09-14 01:00:00 | 278.0 | 278.1 | 276.7 | 277.6 | 16139.244 | 2022-09-14 01:59:59.999 |
| 2411 | 2022-09-14 02:00:00 | 277.5 | 280.1 | 277.4 | 279.5 | 13583.474 | 2022-09-14 02:59:59.999 |
| 2412 | 2022-09-14 03:00:00 | 279.6 | 280.7 | 278.9 | 280.0 | 13142.362 | 2022-09-14 03:59:59.999 |
| 2413 | 2022-09-14 04:00:00 | 280.1 | 282.0 | 279.9 | 281.5 | 13518.034 | 2022-09-14 04:59:59.999 |
| 2414 | 2022-09-14 05:00:00 | 281.4 | 281.8 | 280.0 | 280.3 | 9906.908 | 2022-09-14 05:59:59.999 |
| 2415 | 2022-09-14 06:00:00 | 280.3 | 281.2 | 278.4 | 278.6 | 14126.511 | 2022-09-14 06:59:59.999 |
| 2416 | 2022-09-14 07:00:00 | 278.6 | 279.7 | 277.1 | 279.1 | 23193.697 | 2022-09-14 07:59:59.999 |
| 2417 | 2022-09-14 08:00:00 | 279.1 | 280.2 | 277.2 | 280.1 | 25811.769 | 2022-09-14 08:59:59.999 |
| 2418 | 2022-09-14 09:00:00 | 280.1 | 280.7 | 279.1 | 279.9 | 11960.898 | 2022-09-14 09:59:59.999 |
| 2419 | 2022-09-14 10:00:00 | 279.8 | 280.3 | 279.1 | 279.6 | 11943.115 | 2022-09-14 10:59:59.999 |
| 2420 | 2022-09-14 11:00:00 | 279.6 | 280.5 | 278.0 | 279.6 | 17152.818 | 2022-09-14 11:59:59.999 |
| 2421 | 2022-09-14 12:00:00 | 279.6 | 280.7 | 277.5 | 279.4 | 28562.346 | 2022-09-14 12:59:59.999 |
| 2422 | 2022-09-14 13:00:00 | 279.4 | 282.8 | 278.6 | 281.4 | 32421.324 | 2022-09-14 13:59:59.999 |
| 2423 | 2022-09-14 14:00:00 | 281.3 | 281.4 | 278.6 | 280.2 | 25790.991 | 2022-09-14 14:59:59.999 |
| 2424 | 2022-09-14 15:00:00 | 280.3 | 281.1 | 279.4 | 279.5 | 12341.206 | 2022-09-14 15:59:59.999 |
| 2425 | 2022-09-14 16:00:00 | 279.5 | 279.7 | 278.0 | 278.2 | 18802.725 | 2022-09-14 16:59:59.999 |
| 2426 | 2022-09-14 17:00:00 | 278.1 | 279.5 | 277.7 | 277.8 | 13507.618 | 2022-09-14 17:59:59.999 |
| 2427 | 2022-09-14 18:00:00 | 277.7 | 278.2 | 273.3 | 275.7 | 35438.286 | 2022-09-14 18:59:59.999 |
| 2428 | 2022-09-14 19:00:00 | 275.8 | 277.7 | 275.3 | 277.5 | 13976.371 | 2022-09-14 19:59:59.999 |
| 2429 | 2022-09-14 20:00:00 | 277.5 | 278.4 | 277.3 | 277.9 | 9690.736 | 2022-09-14 20:59:59.999 |
| 2430 | 2022-09-14 21:00:00 | 277.9 | 279.4 | 276.8 | 279.4 | 11821.016 | 2022-09-14 21:59:59.999 |
| 2431 | 2022-09-14 22:00:00 | 279.4 | 280.4 | 278.8 | 279.7 | 17948.597 | 2022-09-14 22:59:59.999 |
| 2432 | 2022-09-14 23:00:00 | 279.8 | 279.9 | 278.7 | 279.3 | 13572.694 | 2022-09-14 23:59:59.999 |

Y este código python:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

## Asuma que aquí fueron declaradas las variables de df_chg_btc, df_chg_eth, df_chg con su respectivos datos

df_chg_btc = df_chg_btc.set_index('Start Date', inplace=False)
df_chg_eth = df_chg_eth.set_index('Start Date', inplace=False)
df_chg = df_chg.set_index('Start Date', inplace=False)

trading_pair = 'BNB/USDT'
start_index = '14 September 2022'

## Plotting using matplotlib and saving the plot in axlist
# Initialize the plot with #162125 as outer color and a figsize of (12, 6)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6), facecolor='#162125')

# Place the indices and values of df_chg,df_chg_btc and df_chg_eth in the x and y axis correspondingly
symbol = trading_pair.replace("USDT", "")+"/"+"USDT"
ax.plot(df_chg.index, df_chg['% Chg'], marker='o', linestyle='-', color='#39c9bb', label=f'{symbol}')  
ax.plot(df_chg_btc.index, df_chg_btc['% Chg'], marker='o', linestyle='-', color='#ff9900', label='BTC/USDT')
ax.plot(df_chg_eth.index, df_chg_eth['% Chg'], marker='o', linestyle='-', color='#8893B1', label='ETH/USDT')

# Set inner color of the plot
ax.set_facecolor("#162125")

# Show every 5th tick to avoid overcrowding
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::5])
# Set the color of x ticks, rotation and the font weight
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), weight='bold', size=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Time UTC', color='white', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
# Format the date on the x-axis
if df_chg.index[1]-df_chg.index[0] == Timedelta(hours=1):
    
    time_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(time_format)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=4))

# Set the color of y ticks and the font weight
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks(), size=10)
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,.2f}%'.format(y) for y in ax.get_yticks()], weight='bold')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')
ax.set_ylabel('% Change', color='white', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')    

# Set the title
if df_chg.index[1]-df_chg.index[0] == Timedelta(hours=1):
    ax.set_title(f'Price Change Comparison - {start_index}', color='white', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')

# Set grid linestyle, width and color
ax.grid(color='white', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)

# Create the legend with customizations
legend = ax.legend(prop={'size': 12, 'weight': 'bold'})

# Customize the legend text color
legend.get_texts()[0].set_color('#162125')
# Set the opacity (alpha) of the legend box
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(1)

plt.tight_layout()

# Update all the spines' outercolors to the same color as facecolor
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_edgecolor('#FFFFFF')

# Save the plot    
filename = start_index+".png"
fig.savefig(+trading_pair+'//'+filename,dpi=300, bbox_inches = "tight")

#RELEASE THE MEMORY RAM
plt.close('all')
```

Sin embargo, no tengo idea de cómo trazar correctamente los datos `df_ohlc` ya que cada vez que trato de encontrar una solución, termina terriblemente mal (es decir, obtengo rectángulos verdes y rojos increíblemente grandes que supuestamente representan los datos, se fija una ubicación incorrecta de las velas, además de un eje y adicional que representa el precio del activo...). También traté de encontrar enfoques similares a mi caso, pero no pude encontrar nada en StackOverflow ni en las primeras 4 páginas de Google usando palabras como

> "candlestick plot with price change values matplotlib"

Sería genial si alguien aquí pudiera ayudarme, cualquier enfoque que use matplotlib es bienvenido.

Comment: Tenes la declaracion de las variables `df_chg_btc`, `df_chg_eth` y `df_chg`?

Comment: Podrias probar poniendo barras flotantes. Busque `matplotlib floating bar chart` y encontre esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057341/floating-bar-chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto, me elevé:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def convert_ohlc_prices_to_percentage_values(df):
    # Create a new DataFrame to store the results
    df_result = pd.DataFrame()

    # Add the 'Start Date' column from the original DataFrame to the new DataFrame
    df_result['Start Date'] = df['Start Date']
    # Reset the index accordingly
    df_result.set_index(df.index, inplace=True)
    for col in df.columns:
        if 'Price' in col:
            # Calculate the result using the formula
            result = round((df[col] - df['Open Price'].iat[0]) / df['Open Price'].iat[0] * 100, 2)

            # Replace values equal to 'Open Price'.iat[0]' with 0
            result = result.where(result != 0, 0)

            # Add the result to the new DataFrame
            df_result[col] = result
        
    # Add the 'Volume' and 'End Date' column from the original DataFrame to the new DataFrame
    df_result['Volume'] = df['Volume']
    df_result['End Date'] = df['End Date']    

    return df_result

## Asuma que aquí fueron declaradas las variables de df_ohlc, df_chg_btc, df_chg_eth, df_chg con su respectivos datos

df_chg_btc = df_chg_btc.set_index('Start Date', inplace=False)
df_chg_eth = df_chg_eth.set_index('Start Date', inplace=False)
df_chg = df_chg.set_index('Start Date', inplace=False)
df_ohlc_percentages = convert_ohlc_prices_to_percentage_values(df_ohlc)

trading_pair = 'BNB/USDT'
start_index = '14 September 2022'

## Plotting using matplotlib and saving the plot in axlist
# Initialize the plot with #162125 as outer color and a figsize of (12, 6)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6), facecolor='#162125')

# Place the indices and values of df_chg,df_chg_btc and df_chg_eth in the x and y axis correspondingly
symbol = trading_pair.replace("USDT", "")+"/"+"USDT"
ax.plot(df_chg.index, df_chg['% Chg'], marker='o', linestyle='-', color='#39c9bb', label=f'{symbol}')  
ax.plot(df_chg_btc.index, df_chg_btc['% Chg'], marker='o', linestyle='-', color='#ff9900', label='BTC/USDT')
ax.plot(df_chg_eth.index, df_chg_eth['% Chg'], marker='o', linestyle='-', color='#8893B1', label='ETH/USDT')

# Creación del gráfico de velas
# Calcula la anchura según el intervalo de tiempo (15 minutos en este caso)
time_diff = df_ohlc_percentages["Start Date"].diff().mean()
width = 0.6 * time_diff
for index, row in df_ohlc_percentages.iterrows():
    open_price = row["Open Price"]
    close_price = row["Close Price"]
    high_price = row["High Price"]
    low_price = row["Low Price"]
    date = row["Start Date"]

    color = '#027F7F' if close_price >= open_price else '#FB0000'
    height = abs(close_price - open_price)
    bottom = min(open_price, close_price)

    ax.bar(date, height, width=width, bottom=bottom, align='center', color=color)
    ax.vlines(x=date, ymin=low_price, ymax=high_price, color=color, linewidth=1)

# Set inner color of the plot
ax.set_facecolor("#162125")

# Show every 5th tick to avoid overcrowding
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::5])
# Set the color of x ticks, rotation and the font weight
ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), weight='bold', size=10)
ax.set_xlabel('Time UTC', color='white', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
# Format the date on the x-axis
if df_chg.index[1]-df_chg.index[0] == Timedelta(hours=1):
    
    time_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(time_format)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=4))

# Set the color of y ticks and the font weight
ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks(), size=10)
ax.set_yticklabels(['{:,.2f}%'.format(y) for y in ax.get_yticks()], weight='bold')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')
ax.set_ylabel('% Change', color='white', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')    

# Set the title
if df_chg.index[1]-df_chg.index[0] == Timedelta(hours=1):
    ax.set_title(f'Price Change Comparison - {start_index}', color='white', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')

# Set grid linestyle, width and color
ax.grid(color='white', linestyle='--', linewidth=1)

# Create the legend with customizations
legend = ax.legend(prop={'size': 12, 'weight': 'bold'})

# Customize the legend text color
legend.get_texts()[0].set_color('#162125')
# Set the opacity (alpha) of the legend box
legend.get_frame().set_alpha(1)

plt.tight_layout()

# Update all the spines' outercolors to the same color as facecolor
for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_edgecolor('#FFFFFF')

# Save the plot    
filename = start_index+".png"
fig.savefig(+trading_pair+'//'+filename,dpi=300, bbox_inches = "tight")

#RELEASE THE MEMORY RAM
plt.close('all')
```

Básicamente lo que tuve que hacer fue:

1. Convertir los precios de `df_ohlc` a valores porcentuales con respecto al primer precio de apertura de la columna `["Open Price"]`. Para esto fue creada la función `convert_ohlc_prices_to_percentage_values(df)`.
2. Luego antes de proceder a poner las velas, tuve que definir la anchura que estás tendrían porque de lo contrario se "*tiran la gráfica*", para esto tuve que tener en cuenta la diferencia media entre los valores de `["Start Date"]` y multiplicarlas por una constante (`0.6`), luego uso 2 for loops para poner cada velita, por medio de los métodos `.bar()` y `.vlines()` y voilá.

> **Salida:**

[image: Salida deseada]

Sí alguien tiene una alternativa es bienvenida.